# Is html structured, unstructured or semi structured data?

Tags: html, structured-data

I am not sure if html belongs to structured, semi-structured or unstructured data. I hope you can answer me this question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

HTML is semi structured. It contains tags and elements with definitive properties and hierarchies. However, the order and number of those tags varies from document to document.

Answer (score 0):

HTML is semi-structured, because we can organize different kind of data in tags.

For example `<P>` for paragraphs and `<ul>` for lists, adding attributes to tags and etc.

Answer (score 0):

HTML is a hierachical tree data structure. For example, XML and XLST are both hierarchical tree data structures that produce a structured hierarchical tree data structure. See Microsoft XSLT and XSLT Programmers Reference from Wrox. Therefore, from a definitional point of view HTML is a data structure.